# Call varibale from constructor and output in another function

Tags: php, class

i want to call a variable of my constructor, how do i do this in PHP?

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    function __constructor() {
        $temp["var_1"] = $_POST['var_1'];
        $temp["var_2"] = $_POST['var_2'];
    }

    function firstMethod() {
        echo 'output var 1 from contructor';
        echo $this->temp["var_1"];
    }

    function secMethod() {
        echo 'output var 2 from contructor';
        echo 'test2';
        echo $this->temp["var_2"];
    }

}
```

Background of my question:

I have a form with lots of configuration. After click on the save button the different methos create different parts of an PHP-File.

The method are using the same variable.

How do i send this information to the different methods?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Your class code should not be "pulling in" superglobal variables. Also, if your class has a huge amount of constructor parameters, you might need to split it up. It is of the warning signs, that your class has too many responsibilities.

Comment: Hello teresko, so do you have a good advise for me? the formular will create a design pattern with a lot of different content areas.. when the areas was created i also create a json file.. afterwards the input fields are not needed any more.. but if you have a better idea! i'm very, very thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$this` when you are trying to define your variables to make it globally callable within the class context :

```
function __constructor() {
    $this->temp["var_1"] = $_POST['var_1'];
    $this->temp["var_2"] = $_POST['var_2'];
}
```

also it's a good practice to define your properties (variables) [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) :

```
public $temp = array();

function __constructor() {
    $this->temp["var_1"] = $_POST['var_1'];
    $this->temp["var_2"] = $_POST['var_2'];
}
```

also to make benefits from the OOP nature, you need to make your object is a stand-alone object so to speak,

plug in any out-sourced variables as a parameters like following :

```
public $temp = array();

function __constructor($data)
{
    $this->temp["var_1"] = $data['var_1'];
    $this->temp["var_2"] = $data['var_2'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Object -Oriented Programming via php, use `$this` in your construct function. ALso you will need to declare the variables to be used in your construct . You also had a typo in `constructor`. Change to `construct`

```
class MyClass {

    var $temp = array();//declare as array

    function __construct($postedVariables) {//pass $_POST here
        $this->temp["var_1"] = $postedVariables['var_1'];//now this variable can be used throughout this class(Filter this variable)
        $this->temp["var_2"] = $postedVariables['var_2'];//now this variable can be used throughout this class(Filter this variable)
    }

    function firstMethod() {
        echo 'output var 1 from contructor';
        echo $this->temp["var_1"];
    }

    function secMethod() {
        echo 'output var 2 from contructor';
        echo 'test2';
        echo $this->temp["var_2"];
    }

}
//call your class as:
$myCLass = new MyClass($_POST);//pass your post array
```